# nested foreach doesnt work as planned, duplicates everything in first array. (Prestashop invoice)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to make a function for Prestashop which adds a reminder fee and also changing the state from invoice to reminder. on overdue invoices.
The code below handles the request after previous step which is choosing a date interval. 
This works like a charm, however, I'm stuck here.

`foreach($order_invoice_collection as $invoice)` is supposed to add ONE product called reminders fee to each order, but it keeps adding multiple products on each order (same amount as total orders in array).

I need to do this because its the only way i can see how to access the correct `id_order_invoice`.

I would really appreciate any help here!

```
public function processGenerateInvoicesPDF6() {
    // switch do update ON/OFF
    $should_update = Tools::getValue("should_update");
    // end switch
    $order_numbers = explode(",", Tools::getValue("order_ids"));

    if(strpos(Tools::getValue("order_ids"),'-') !== false) {
        $order_numbers = explode("-", Tools::getValue("order_ids"));
        $order_numbers = range($order_numbers[0], $order_numbers[1]);
    }
    $order_invoice_collection = array();
    foreach($order_numbers as $order_number) {
        if($order_number != "") {
            $order = new Order($order_number);
            // Switch
            if($should_update) {
                // switch
                $order->current_state += 1;
                $order->total_paid_tax_incl += 60;
                $order->total_paid_tax_excl += 60;
                $order->total_paid += 60;
                $order->update();

               if(is_array($order_invoices = $order->getInvoicesCollection()->getResults())) {
                   $order_invoice_collection = array_merge($order_invoices, $order_invoice_collection); }

                   foreach($order_invoice_collection as $invoice) {
                       $order_detail = new OrderDetail();
                       $order_detail->id_order = $order->id;
                       $order_detail->id_order_invoice = $invoice->id;
                       $order_detail->product_name = "Påminnelseavgift";
                       $order_detail->id_shop = 1;
                       $order_detail->product_id = 999999;
                       $order_detail->product_quantity = 1;
                       $order_detail->product_quantity_in_stock = 1;
                       $order_detail->tax_name = "";
                       $order_detail->product_weight = 0;
                       $order_detail->id_warehouse = 0;
                       $order_detail->product_price = 60;
                       $order_detail->total_price_tax_incl = 60;
                       $order_detail->total_price_tax_excl = 60;
                       $order_detail->unit_price_tax_excl = 60;
                       $order_detail->unit_price_tax_incl = 60;
                       $order_detail->save();
                    }
                    $orderHistory = new OrderHistory();
                    $orderHistory->id_order = $order->id;
                    $orderHistory->id_order_state = $order->current_state;
                    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $orderHistory->date_add = pSQL($datetime);
                    $orderHistory->save();
                    //end test switch
                }
                // end test switch
            }
        }

        if(count($order_invoice_collection) == 0) {
            Tools::redirectAdmin($this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminInvoices'));
        }

        $this->generatePDF($order_invoice_collection, PDF::TEMPLATE_INVOICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why are you making it so complicated, but you have nested two `foreach`, so `$order_invoice_collection` grows bigger on every loop and bacame doubled, because `$order_invoice_collection = array();` is outside these loops. I'd recommend to make a special `Order status` and assign a reminder fee on changing to this `order state` with a hook `actionOrderStatusUpdate`.

Comment: Im kinda new in prestashop, could you point me in The right direction regarding exactly how to accomplish that? @Indrė  i would be most grateful!

Comment: You need to start from here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module and here https://validator.prestashop.com/generator.